# Type safety raw type with Stream in java

Tags: java, arrays, warnings

I am using stream/arrays to convert a `JSONArray` to a `String[]`.
The library used for json is: [jsonsimple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/)

The one liner of this is the following:

```
import org.json.simple.parser.*;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

    // other stuff

        try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(
                "/home/hduser/eclipse-workspace/db-simulatiob/src/generator-config.json")) {

            // Get config json
            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
            JSONObject aTags = (JSONObject) obj.get("assembling-tags");
        String[] assemblingTags = (String[]) ((JSONArray) aTags.get("list")).stream().toArray(String[]::new); <---- one liner
```

But it returns the warning:

> Type safety: The method toArray(IntFunction) belongs to the raw type
>   Stream. References to generic type Stream should be parameterized

According to [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147204/type-safety-the-method-belongs-to-the-raw-type-refs-to-generics-should-be-p), I have to give an explicit type, OK.

Not being able to figure it out o the one liner, I split the one liner in three and tried to suppress the warning on this new version. So far I have this:

```
    JSONArray temp = (JSONArray) aTags.get("list");
    Stream<JSONArray> ts = temp.stream();  <=== warning here
    String[] tss = (String[]) ts.toArray(String[]::new);
```

But it still returns the same warning on the second line on `temp.stream();`.

**How can I fix the code to suppress the warning ?**

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example? What is `aTags` and which package (library) does the class `JSONArray` come from?

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly cast your Stream? `Stream<JSONArray> ts = (Stream<JSONArray>) temp.stream();`

Comment: @Abrikot Returns ``Type safety: Unchecked cast from Stream to Stream<JSONArray>``. A warning for another warning :D

Comment: @FlorianCastelain Well, that's not better! Have you tried to do `temp.toArray()`? My IDE tells me it should work :)

Comment: I can, it returns an Object[] variable. I'll have to change it to String[] though. I'm good with this, however I'm not really sure it can be marked as a solution as it looks more like a workaround. @Abrikot

Comment: From [the documentation](http://miamarti.github.io/HorusFramework/javadoc/org/json/simple/JSONArray.html), I see that org.json.simple.JSONArray extends the raw type java.util.ArrayList.  That is why you are getting raw type warnings.  I recommend using a better JSON library;  there are many available.

Comment: Not sure, too. I have had this type of warning a lot of time and all I have done was to ignore it (with @Matteo solution). I would say that, when you are 100% sure of what you're doing, it's not an issue to suppress the warning.

Comment: @Abrikot Suppressing warnings is a very bad practice that will lead to code that breaks in unexpected ways.  Never suppress warnings.  In Java, warnings mean your code is syntactically correct but logically incorrect.

Comment: @VGR Do you have any recommendation for java json library ?

Comment: I don’t know much about the various JSON libraries.  Personally, I use the [javax.json](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html) package which is part of Java EE.  You can obtain it by downloading a “full platform” version of GlassFish from [here](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/download), then copying its glassfish/modules/javax.json.jar file into your project.  It appears [Maven also has it](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api).

Comment: @VGR If you don't suppress warning but can't use anything else than what is already provided (such as the raw ArrayList given by jsonsimple), what should you do? Sometimes I think it's better to hide this warning because it will just pollute your compile logs.

Comment: @FlorianCastelain : You can use GSON. It's probably the best library you can find as of now!

Comment: @Abrikot There’s always a way to do it without @SuppressWarnings.  In this case, `((Collection<?>) aTags.get("list"))` would probably do it.

Comment: Meh, if warnings were always resulting in problems they would be called errors. Local suppression of the exception in `Stream<JSONArray> ts = temp.stream();` seems a good idea **if** you want to keep to that specific library, and really the only option. Don't do it on the one liner and keep people guessing which error is being suppressed though. I'd be very suspicious of any library that returns raw data types though; is it being maintained?

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica javac does have a `-Werror` option, which I use.  I agree that it appears jsonsimple hasn’t been maintained since before Java 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code works, and you are sure is what you want, have you tried?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
String[] tss = (String[]) ts.toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: I considered this, but did not try because what I would like is not to suppress a warning, but to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get as in the last question you asked how to suppress warning